# how to read xml file data from azure service bus queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I just want to read XML file data that i have sent in azure service bus from queue. My code is

```cs
while (client.Peek() != null)
{
    BrokeredMessage orderOutMsg = client.Receive();

    if (orderOutMsg != null)
    {
        // Deserialize the message body to a pizza order.
        XDocument orderOut = orderOutMsg.GetBody<XDocument>();
        Console.WriteLine("Received order, {0} {1} ", orderOut.Root.Element("Customer").Element("Location_Code").Value, orderOut.Root.Element("Customer").Element("Phone_Number").Value);

        orderOutMsg.Complete();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: You should also describe the problem that you get and the steps you made so far to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetBody<T>` tries to deserialize the message into type `T` using `DataContractSerializer`.

What you probably want is just to read a `string` and then parse into XML:

```cs
var body = orderOutMsg.GetBody<string>();
XDocument orderOut = XDocument.Parse(body);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer now my code is working perfectly.

Comment: @ShubhamMittal Welcome! You should mark the answer as approved then.